# Monoshot oscillator with a opamp level shifter gives huge oscillations

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, level-shifting

I am trying to level shift the output of a [LTC6993-3](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6993-6993-1-6993-2-6993-3-6993-4.pdf) using a [THS4631](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths4631.pdf?ts=1613291409160&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) based level shifter.

I get a 0-5V output which I want to level shift from -5V to 0V.

I get a clean output from the monoshot but, the output has huge spikes after the level shift stage.

Below is my schematic and outputs.[image: Schematic and outputs]

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: That's normal if you don't compensate with Cf

Comment: Where can we compensate using Cf- opamp or monoshot

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @Tony Stewart Sunnyskyguy EE75 answers it all, I added a capacitor in parallel with my feedback resistor for lead compenstaion and that removed my oscillations. Now I get a clean waveform.[image: Waveforms]

Comment: 10 pF ought to be enough , but 300 MHz is overkill anyways